# caulk type for bathrooms/washrooms

Tags: bathroom, caulking, caulk

What type of caulk is used in bathrooms? I need to caulk between a bathtub and a tiled wall. Can I use the same for caulking around lavatory pan?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you want is a [siliconized *latex* caulk](http://www.dap.com/dap-products-ph/alex-plus-acrylic-latex-caulk-plus-silicone/). The silicone will resist the water better and the latex will make cleanup easy.

Pure silicone is another option, but it's much harder to clean up and nearly impossible to scrape off later in some cases. It's also got a LOT more VOCs, so expect it to smell bad for a while.

Answer (score 1):

Usually, Silicone (clear) or Siliconized (colored). This type is good for most anywhere inside or outside the house. So yes, your intent is perfect usage of such a caulk throughout the bathroom.